# Conexão com banco de dados SQL no C#

Tags: c#, banco-de-dados, visual-studio

Bom dia amigos,

estou com duvida sobre conexão com banco de dados em especial para o uso em um projeto que captura as informações do banco para um DataGridView , meu primeiro problema é que as informações da tabela não estão vindo, minha duvida, eu consigo conectar o banco de dados apenas com a string de conexão, ou eu preciso além da string de conexão adicionar o banco pelo data base Configuration wizard do visual studio ?

Comment: Ao definir a string de conexão, nela você também defini o database no qual quer ter acesso.

Por exemplo:  connectionString="Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=MEUBD;Integrated Security=True"

Comment: hum entendi, eu estou usando objetos para acessar o banco :
    public class DAOUtils
    {
        public static DbConnection GetConexao()
        {
            string cnx = @"Server=./SQLExpress14;Database=Silo;User Id=sa;Password=avila1334;";
            DbConnection conexao = new SqlConnection(cnx);
            conexao.Open();
            return conexao;

Comment: Pode estar ai o meu erro ?

Comment: Retorna algum erro? Porque você só está conectando ao banco, mas não executa nenhuma query.

Comment: isso, ele não retorna nada

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veja se esse exemplo lhe ajuda:

```
SqlConnection sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection("Your Connection String");
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
SqlDataReader reader;

cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Customers";
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1;

sqlConnection1.Open();

reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
// Aqui os dados são acessados através do objeto dataReader
sqlConnection1.Close();
```

Comment: Muito obrigado Vinicios, descobri o que estava acontecendo, não estava colocando o DGV para carregar corretamento no form , porisso os dados não vinham , acabou que estava achando que o problema era o banco, valeu amigo